# how to save my datatable data ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, datatable

I need to save all the data that is in my `datatable`

How could I add a general button that keeps everything in my datatable?

This in my current `Project` :

```js
var table = $('#listaDocumentos').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ],
    language: {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No hay información",
        "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Ultimo",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<table id="listaDocumentos" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Question is bit unclear! what you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to send to save this data: Name, Position, Office, age, start date Salary

Comment: Hi, please check the answer. i think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is 
you need to save data which is currently showing in the view(Html page) as tabular format.

In this case you can use jquery or javascript like below to get the data.

```
var table = $("table tbody");

table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
// comment loop through the tr and get value of every td within this tr tag
var tds = $(this).find('td');
var  Name = $tds.eq(0).text();
var Position = $tds.eq(1).text();
var office = $tds.eq(2).text();
var age = $tds.eq(3).text();
var startPosition = $tds.eq(4).text();
var salary = $tds.eq(5).text();
});
```

Then bind a button in view like

```
<input type="button" id="btn_data_save" value="Save Data"/>
```

Then an ajax call to pass the data to server. WIthin that call you need to collect all the value and build an array of object.

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_data_save', function(){
    var ary=[];

    var table = $("table tbody");
    table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
    var obj={};
    obj.tds = $(this).find('td');
    obj.name = $tds.eq(0).text();
    obj.position = $tds.eq(1).text();
    obj.office = $tds.eq(2).text();
    obj.age = $tds.eq(3).text();
    obj.startPosition = $tds.eq(4).text();
    obj.salary = $tds.eq(5).text();
    ary.Push(obj);
 });

$.ajax({ 
     type: 'POST', 
     url: '', 
     data: { list: JSON.stringify(ary) }, 
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {      
   }
});
});
```

Finally in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(string list)
{
    //comment do your work    
}
```

Please comment if you do not understand the solution. i will describe if necessary.